# How can I obtain sWeights with zfit?

Tags: zfit, hepstats

I have a fit to the signal region using zfit and fitting with an `ExtendedUnbinnedNLL`. My models are a signal and a background PDF.

How can I obtain the *sWeights* for background subtraction?

I had a look already at *hepstats*, they seem to provide many high-level tools. However, it was not clear to me how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to directly use the `compute_sweights` function provided by hepstats. Assuming you have your models `signal` and `background`, both fit extended to data, that would read as

```py
from hepstats.splot import compute_sweights

sweights = compute_sweights(zfit.pdf.SumPDF([signal, background]), data)

bkg_sweights = sweights[Nbkg]
sig_sweights = sweights[Nsig]
```